# Moolavar and Utsavar

Tags: vishnu, puranas, advaita, vaishnavism, sri-vaishnava

It seems that in every temple (predominantly Vishnu Temples, I am not that very sure about all Shiva temples, please correct me if I am wrong) there are 2 presiding deities, namely, Moolavar and Utsavar.

As far as I know, the Utsavar deity is taken out of the Garbha griha for processions and other riutals around the temple (inside and outside the temple as well).

My question is:

1. So, the Moolavar is created with stone and cannot be moved. The Utsavar is made out of metal and small and hence can be taken out for processions. Is this the only difference between the two?
2. Is there any concept of Syambu of Moolavar or Utsavar? Are all Moolavar or Utsavars, Syambu's or some of them of certain temples are?
3. In certain temples, there seem to be more than 1 Utsavar moorthy. For example, in Thiruvellikeni Parathasarathy temple, there seems to be 5 Utsavars? How is this? Can someone elaborate more on this?